# Google Ad-exchange API, curl connect, login and retrieve report working inconsistently

Tags: php, curl, google-api

It worked for a while then it stopped working and it worked again yesterday and it's not working today.

the error I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{\n "error": {\n  "errors": [\n   {\n    "domain": "global",\n    "reason": "authError",\n    "message": "Invalid Credentials",\n    "locationType": "header",\n    "location": "Authorization"\n   }\n  ],\n  "code": 401,\n  "message": "Invalid Credentials"\n }\n}\n' in /var/www/html/apis/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:123\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/apis/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(82): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), 'Google_Service_...')\n#1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), 'Google_Service_...')\n#2 /var/www/html/apis/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(181): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#3 /var/www/html/apis/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(57): Google_Task_Runner->run()\n#4 /var/www/html/apis/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php(758): in /var/www/html/apis/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 123
```

I am login in through curl and this seems to work as I get an access token which is still valid

the error occurs when I try to retrieve anything :

```
if ($accessToken = $client->getAccessToken()) {
 $_SESSION['access_token'] = $accessToken;

  print_r($_SESSION['access_token']) ;
   makeRequests($service);
}

function makeRequests($service){
  print_r($service->accounts->listAccounts());

}
```

returns:

```
    "Array
(
    [access_token] => ya29.dQIbso28HXjc-7kdkK0_rNBPih28TMuu_liEf-I330l8Mrw2qWoh........
    [token_type] => Bearer
    [expires_in] => 3600
    [created] => 1453806361
)"
```

if I echo something in the function makeRequest it works.

thanks you for your help

UPDATE:
it worked for a bit, and now the token has expired and it stopped working. However my code should refresh the token:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
}
```

I also have the access type set to offline

```
$client->setAccessType('offline');
```

but the access token time and expiry are still in the past:

```
Array
(
    [access_token] => ya29.dQIbso28HXjc-7kdkK0_rNBPih28TMuu_liEf-I330l8Mrw2qWohLHO4jr3kSc1s5nfl0g
    [token_type] => Bearer
    [expires_in] => 3600
    [created] => 1453806361
)
```

Comment: just a few minutes after posting the question it worked again... with no change whatsoever... even the token details are identical... I am puzzled

Comment: check the time on the machine you are running this on.

Comment: time is correct. It gave me hope though for about 20 seconds.

Comment: the access token is going to expire after an hour you know right?

Comment: yes it has now expired but, as updated above, I understood it should refresh on my next request.. however it doesn't seem to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same error appeared for me.
I have been researching about this error for a while, and I realized that a revocation take time to have full effect as described in the [official document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke).
In my environment, it takes about 20 minutes to re-access user's data after a revocation.

Here's my presumption.

①If I revoke the access, the access token and refresh token will be invalid. so you cannot access the user's data.

②After that, When I reauthorize the access in 20 minutes after the revocation, the user's state is still "revoking" on the google's server. So you can't access the user's data with the new valid access token obtained by the reauthorization.

③After 20 minutes, the revocation will be "completed" on google's server, so you can access the user's data with the new access token.

Any other possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found a solution by deleting the cookie storing the access token, before the request, in order to request a new token